# Optimization of plsql procedure which involves loop based insert on a table including clob columns

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, bulkinsert, clob

Please help with the following kind of procedural code which I need to tune. The basic premise is that I need to select data and insert into a table. I could have directly done an insert into select but there is clob column calculation required for each row.

Following is the table and the code.

```
    create table test_clob_performance
(col1 number , col2 number , col3 number , col4 number , col5 number , col6 number , col7 number , col8 number 
, clob1 clob , clob2 clob , clob3 clob , clob4 clob) ;



-- This is just a test function actual function derives ddata from tables on the basis of the input parameters
create or replace function some_func_for_clob(val number)
return clob
is 
begin
return rpad('test clob' , val , '*');
exception when others then 
raise_application_error(-20001 , sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_stack);
end;




create or replace 
PROCEDURE insert_clob_performance IS

   CURSOR c1  IS
   SELECT  rownum  as col1, rownum+1 col2, rownum+1 col3, rownum+4 col4, rownum+5 col5,rownum+6 col6, rownum+7 col7
   , rownum+8  col8 from dual connect by rownum < 10000 ;

      var_clob1            CLOB;
      var_clob2           CLOB;
      var_clob3          CLOB;
      var_clob4           CLOB;

 BEGIN


   FOR z IN c1   LOOP

     var_clob1 := some_func_for_clob(z.col1 );
     var_clob2 := some_func_for_clob(z.col1 );
     var_clob3 := some_func_for_clob(z.col1 );
     var_clob4 := some_func_for_clob(z.col1 );

  INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO test_clob_performance (col1 , col2 , col3 , col4 , col5 ,col6 , col7 , col8,clob1 , clob2 , clob3 , clob4)
  values (z.col1 , z.col2 , z.col3 , z.col4 , z.col5 ,z.col6 , z.col7 , z.col8,var_clob1 , var_clob2 , var_clob3 , var_clob4);


    END LOOP;
  END ;

 /
```

For example, executing insert_clob_performance takes 17 seconds to complete in 12.2 Oracle database. When I try to improve this using bulk collect the performance gets worse and insert_clob_performance_opt  takes 23 seconds to complete. 
Even if I change the limit clause to only 100 the performance is as similar to the original code.

Please suggest what can be done to improve the performance here.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE insert_clob_performance_opt IS

   CURSOR c1  IS
   SELECT  rownum  as col1, rownum+1 col2, rownum+1 col3, rownum+4 col4, rownum+5 col5,rownum+6 col6, rownum+7 col7
   , rownum+8  col8 , '', '' , '' , '' from dual connect by rownum < 10000 ;

      var_clob1            CLOB;
      var_clob2           CLOB;
      var_clob3          CLOB;
      var_clob4           CLOB;

      type clob_perf_rec is table of test_clob_performance%rowtype ;
      clob_perf_tab clob_perf_rec;

 BEGIN

open c1 ;

  LOOP

  FETCH c1 bulk collect into clob_perf_tab LIMIT 1000;

  exit when clob_perf_tab.count = 0 ;

  for i in clob_perf_tab.first .. clob_perf_tab.last loop
    clob_perf_tab(i).clob1 := some_func_for_clob(clob_perf_tab(i).col1 );
    clob_perf_tab(i).clob2 := some_func_for_clob(clob_perf_tab(i).col2 );
    clob_perf_tab(i).clob3 := some_func_for_clob(clob_perf_tab(i).col3 );
    clob_perf_tab(i).clob4 := some_func_for_clob(clob_perf_tab(i).col4 );
  end loop;

  forall i in clob_perf_tab.first .. clob_perf_tab.last
    INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO test_clob_performance (col1 , col2 , col3 , col4 , col5 ,col6 , col7 , col8,clob1 , clob2 , clob3 , clob4)
    values (clob_perf_tab(i).col1 , clob_perf_tab(i).col2 , clob_perf_tab(i).col3 , clob_perf_tab(i).col4 , 
    clob_perf_tab(i).col5 ,clob_perf_tab(i).col6 , clob_perf_tab(i).col7 , clob_perf_tab(i).col8,
    clob_perf_tab(i).clob1 , clob_perf_tab(i).clob2 , clob_perf_tab(i).clob3 , clob_perf_tab(i).clob4);


    END LOOP;
  END ;
```

Comment: What is the timing when you skip the "some_func_for_clob" and just do the insert with original clob value?

Comment: 0.254 seconds ,clob columns are null by default here.

Comment: So it's not the loop, it's the clob processing that takes so long?

Comment: yeah it looks like so, without clob insert takes lesser time, i ran dbms_profiler to check this, most of the time is taken by insert itself with clobs. With clobs as null inserts are very fast even if they execute 9999 times

Comment: The APPEND hint doesn't seem to be working, otherwise it would throw an error because there is no `COMMIT` between direct-path writes.  Maybe try APPEND_VALUES with a `COMMIT`, or investigate the table and see what if anything is preventing direct-path writes.

Comment: Doing SQL in a row-by-row is always going to be worse that doing it in a single SQL statement. That's why it's called "slow-by-slow". And the insert might not be your bottleneck. It could be this mystery function with `CLOB` out parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that with a single insert-from-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO test_clob_performance (col1 , col2 , col3 , col4 , col5 ,col6 , col7 , col8,clob1 , clob2 , clob3 , clob4)
SELECT col1 , col2 , col3 , col4 , col5 ,col6 , col7 , col8, some_func_for_clob(col1), some_func_for_clob(col2), some_func_for_clob(col3), some_func_for_clob(col4) 
FROM
(SELECT  rownum  as col1, rownum+1 col2, rownum+1 col3, rownum+4 col4, rownum+5 col5,rownum+6 col6, rownum+7 col7, rownum+8 col8 from dual connect by rownum < 10000) ;
```

Comment: I have written in my description that "I could have directly done a insert into select but there is clob column calculation required for each row.". This is just a demo code actual code looks similar to this but in no way i can do this thing in single insert into select

Comment: There is clob calculation for each row in the above query.

Comment: "in no way i can do this thing in single insert into select". Honestly, I quite doubt about that. Can you explain why you can't?

Comment: because that function is more like a function with clob as return type and other clobs as it output parameters. so the code is more like "  var_clob1 := some_function(val , var_clob2 , var_clob3 , var_clob4) " instead of multiple assignment statements for each clob variable. Also this is 800 lines of code this function and i dont want to get into changing it

Comment: You may try to provide the NOCOPY hint for output arguments of the function if they are missing (if it's possible, of course) and see if it helps. But i'm affraid there's nothing much you can do about it if you do not want to change the function.

Comment: thanks for the help man. Can bulk collect and forall not help with performance improvement in this case?

Comment: You can try different LIMIT values in insert_clob_performance_opt procedure, but I don't think you'll benefit from it. My guess the root of the problem is located inside the function, so that's where I'd start from.